# How to display detached view menu item in view in eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In 3.x detached view menu item was displayed in view parts, but seems like it is no more supported in 4.x, is there any way to display detached view option in views in eclipse 4 as well?

Comment: In a pure e4 app you will have to code this yourself.

Comment: I am migrating 3.x application to 4.x using compat layer so this is not pure e4 app. Is there any way if i am using compat layer?